# Netsuite custom field not filterable

Tags: netsuite

Why would a field in a custom record not respond to a filter when searched?  I filter using that field and it's as though I'm not even passing a filter.

[image]
There should only be one result when the filter is used as there is only one record where that filter evaluates to true.

Cheers,
PJ

Comment: Really shouldn't be an issue. What type of field is custrecord_al_sequence?

Have you tried:
    `var filters = [new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_al_sequence', null, 'anyof', [1])];`

Comment: It's a number integer field.  The anyof, as well as noneof, produce the same result.  Is there something special that needs to be done to make the field 'filterable'?

Comment: number fields are different: `var filters = [new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_al_sequence', null, 'equalto', 1)];`

Comment: That did it, many thanks.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You've wrapped the standard search so who can tell? What does `Netsuite.search` look like?

Comment: Woops, it's just a shortcut to runSearch and getResults, but I'll redo the screencap with nlapiCreateSearch('customrecord_approval_levels', filters, columns).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last sentence, I am assuming you are getting more than one search result?

If so, then you might be retrieving inactive records.  Try adding the filter

```
nlapiSearchFilter('isinactive',null, 'is', 'F')
```

If you do not include this filter on custom record search, NetSuite gets inactive and active records.

Comment: Unfortunately, all three are active and adding that filter doesn't alter the result.  Good thinking though, I hadn't considered that issue.

Answer (score 0):

As bknights pointed out, the operator needs to be 'equalto', not is.  All credit to bknights.